# Attached document in SOAP request (MTOM), does not arrive at webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, request, mtom

I've created a SOAP webserice that upload document (using MTOM), but on the server side the DataHandler object is empty (dataHandler.getInputStream is empty too).

[my dataHandler object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtK2x.png)

And this is the document in my request:

```
<content><inc:Include href="cid:BP_275627594_SP39274815_46048927_49441074-49441075_1666846379.pdf" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></content>
```

[My request properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxPWu.png)

I've tried to solve it this way:

```
    <xs:element name="DocumentRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Level" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="content" type="xs:base64Binary" xmime:expectedContentTypes="*/*"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "DocumentRequest")
public class DocumentRequest
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String ID;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String Level;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlMimeType("*/*")
    protected DataHandler content;
```

```
@MTOM(enabled = true)
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "DocumentRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public DocumentResponse document(@RequestPayload DocumentRequest request) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(request.getContent().getInputStream().available());
```

In summary, why I can't reach the attached file from code?

Thank You!